# Send Http Post Request with string Format Using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to use Alamofire in my project, there is my own code for send request to server, that's work good, but when use Alamofire always get timeout response, How can send request with http header : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in Alamofire.

this is my request :

```
func fetchRequest(completion: @escaping (RequestResult) -> Void){

        let myUrl = NSURL(string: stringForUrl)
        var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl as! URL )

 let param = ["userid":"59","key":"sofah@#^!*FDS#","action":"vitrin","step":"list","sort": "","filter":"","start":String(""),"end":String("")]

        request.setURLEncodedFormData(parameters: params as! [String : String])


        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error)  in

            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse

            if  httpResponse == response as? HTTPURLResponse {

                guard let data = data else {


                    print("No data in server")
                    return
                }

                let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                print("responseString = \(responseString)")

                let statusCode = httpResponse?.statusCode
                print(statusCode ?? "")
            }


            let result = self.processRequest(data: data, error: error as NSError?)

            // completion closure that will be called once the web service request is completed.
            completion(result)
        })
        task.resume()
    }

extension URLRequest {

  private static let alloweCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 -_.*@$!#")

  public mutating func setURLEncodedFormData(parameters: [String: String?])  {

    var encodedParameters = ""

    for (key, value) in parameters {

      if !encodedParameters.isEmpty {
        encodedParameters += "&"
      }

      encodedParameters += URLRequest.urlEncoded(value: key)
      encodedParameters += "="

      if let valuee = value {
        encodedParameters += URLRequest.urlEncoded(value: valuee)
      }
    }

    self.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    self.httpBody = encodedParameters.data(using: .utf8)
  }


  private static func urlEncoded(value: String) -> String {

    return value.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: alloweCharacters)!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
  }

}
```

send request use Alamofire :

```
 func sendRequestUsingAlamofire() {


    let param = ["userid":"59" ,"key":"sofah@#^!*FDS#","action":"vitrin","step":"list","sort": "","filter":"","start":String(""),"end":String("")]

    let url =  "http://www.***/service/index.php"


    let ulrRequest =  NSURL(string:url)
    var request = URLRequest(url: ulrRequest as! URL )


    request.setURLEncodedFormData(parameters: param as! [String : String])

        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in

          switch (response.result) {
          case .success:
            //do json stuff
            break
          case .failure(let error):

            print(error)
            if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
              //timeout here
            }
            print("\n\nAuth request failed with error:\n \(error)")
            break
          }


        })

  }
```

where is my problem when using Alamofire ? 
thanks

Comment: At what point in your code do you indicate that you wish to use the HTTP verb 'POST'?

Comment: If you use the 'POST' method, you can write "Alamofire.request('http://xxxxx', method: .post, parameters: param)". Alamofire default Content-Type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8".

Comment: @Takahiro when use this format i don't get any response.

Comment: @Takahiro i am get this log in console : Auth request failed with error:
 responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)

Comment: I understand this API need request contains httpBody. So my previous opinion is not good. And your first code is generally no problem. However it doesn't set "POST" method. Then I think you better write "request.HTTPMethod = 'POST'" before execution "Alamofire.request(request)...".